Prismatic joint not moving upwards in Gazebo simulation
I am working on a small forklift URDF model which I am using in Gazebo in conjunction with ROS2 (Jazzy). I am trying to get the fork plate to move upwards by utilizing Gazebo's JointPositionController-plugin, but the plate doesn't move upwards at all, not even to the initial position specified. The joint moves on the y and x-axes as normal. The issue disappears when I disable gravity in my world, so it obviously has something to do with that.
I started working with ROS2 and Gazebo quite recently, and I haven't found many examples on this subject for the Gazebo version I am using (Harmonic). What could be the issue? Am I misunderstanding the usage of the plugin?
The plugin:
<gazebo>
    <plugin filename="gz-sim-joint-position-controller-system" name="gz::sim::systems::JointPositionController">
        <joint_name>fork_plate_joint</joint_name>
        <topic>fork_control</topic>
        <initial_position>0.6</initial_position>
    </plugin>
</gazebo>

The joint URDF:
<joint name="fork_plate_joint" type="prismatic">
     <parent link="track_2"/>
     <child link="fork_plate"/>
     <!--Offset the joint position by the track depth amount-->
     <origin xyz="${track_depth/2} 0 -0.025" rpy="0 0 0" />
     <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
     <limit effort="110" lower="0" upper="0.6" velocity="0.5"/>
</joint>


